# Since we can rescind close votes, lets use 'em

Tags: discussion, tags, vote-to-close

I don't much care what you call it, (I'm going to call it "faith tradition") but if it's not specified in the question, please VTC the question.

This is very important to our success as a site and our ability to attract Catholics (who have to be some kind of idiots to even want to participate here) and Orthodox (who for the most part do not) Otherwise, we should not have a site called "Christianity", it should be called Protestants and all you other guys.

Seriously, imagine StackOverflow where all the questions were about PHP, unless they were tagged Delphi, C++, VB, etc...  That makes absolutely no sense!  Nearly every Catholic question is tagged [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) as it is for LDS and Jehovah's Witnesses and some of the more scholarly [reformed](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed) questions.

Comment: P.S. It's a good thing I wasn't elected mod! I'd have been up all night closing half the site instead of playing with my son's legos.

Comment: Would Catholics then be proscribed from answering generic Christianity questions?

Comment: @pterandon there is no such thing as generic Christianity and if there was it would be Catholicism

Comment: If anyone answers a question from a faith tradition outside of the one specified in the original post, the answer should be downvoted or if it is argumentative and rude or totally off topic it should be flagged and deleted

Comment: You said use your close votes! :)

Comment: @AffableGeek _aha_ two can play at that game!

Comment: Why is "primarily opinion based" a close reason on Meta anyway?

Comment: DOH! I thought I could play the game too, but no. Stupid mod hammer.

Comment: I assume this is closed pending your declaration of which churches you wanted an answer from.

Comment: @waxeagle that is something someone ought to post, we can only identify the absence of a "faith tradition" not the presence.

Comment: @PeterTurner huh?

Comment: @wax historical christianity? Questions about patristics? biblical-basis. where do these all fit?

Comment: darned if I know, we're still figuring all that out. it's only been 2 years, people have been fighting about this stuff for far longer than that.

Answer (score 6):

I agree in principle, but I think it may be a bit more difficult than it sounds.

Unlike Catholicism, LDS, and Jehovah's Witnesses, many "faith traditions" do not have a single right answer. For example, it can be difficult to give a single, correct answer to "what do Baptists teach about *x*?" Baptists are technically not ***a* denomination** but are a group/association/coalition of denominational and non-denominational churches, and only agree on a few points (and even then, that agreement is rarely unanimous -- some of them will even argue over [whether Baptists are Protestants](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/9986/4188) or not). For an example, see the answers to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4199/4188) -- somewhat contradictory answers about Baptists churches that really mean nothing.

So before we go and close everything for not meeting objectivity standards (and that is the problem here; many traditions are assumed to be "normal" while others must specify their distinction), we need to actually figure out how this will work. Is a catch-all "Protestant" tag acceptable? The question would have to limit to the specific subset desired, but may (or may not) be better than three hundred tags like "southern-baptist," "american-baptist," and "first-baptist-down-the-street."

Instead of requiring a denominational scope without exception, is there any problem with specifying the belief itself in a tag; any denomination who teaches along the lines of that tag can answer according to their teachings. A question about the Trinity doesn't necessarily need to be tagged Catholicism or Lutheranism; it should specify "the Trinity according to the Nicene (or Athanasian) Creed." All Nicene Christians can answer this from their traditions, so does it really need to exclude somebody unnecessarily?

Comment: I think [tag:protestantism] is acceptable, It's narrower than [tag:catholicism] in terms of number of freewill laden souls, but I don't think anyone agrees with me.

Comment: Yes, as far as I'm concerned this is an OR scenario. Either scope a question to a particular faith tradition OR to a specific belief.

Comment: What Caleb said.

Comment: You are very correct that for most of Christendom, it's not possible to say "the right answer for denomination/belief X".  I've spoken of the controversies in Lutheranism. However, one can quote Luther, *the Book of Concord*, perhaps recent statement or resolution by some parachurch organization (ex: WordAlone), etc.  Answers can be judged on the veracity of the quote and whether logically they relate to the question.

Comment: @Caleb is The Trinity a specific enough belief? I'd say, the Trinity is a fact, the Incarnation is a fact, etc... Sola Scriptura, the Assumption of Mary, etc.. those are beliefs but the definition is very hazy. We could start a list or use tag wikis to define which tags sufficiently scope questions